# Unable to install awscli with pip3

Tags: command-line-interface, aws-cli

This is the error i get when I try to install awscli with pip3 (version 10.0.1).

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.',
OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/awscli/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awscli (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awscli
```

When I try the below command I get the same error as above:

```
pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org awscli
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: what does `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user -v` output?

Comment: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))) - skipping

Comment: looks like there might be a similar error [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5812) and that the issue is more with the PIP than the awscli package. Can you pip install anything else? Which version of pip are you using? Can you update and see if that solve the issues if not the latest?

Comment: I can't install anything with pip. Pip version 10.0.1. I tried upgrading to the latest version, but I just get errors.

Comment: Hmm to confirm that it's an issue with the machine and not the network there can you try a different computer and see if it works there? If we confirm it's just that one machine then can you use `nslookup  pypi.org` and see if the domain is able to be resolved? If it is able to resolve then can you perform a curl request on that same domain and resource `curl -v -sL  https://pypi.org/simple/pip` and show that output?

Comment: can you telnet to that domain on 443? `telnet pypi.org 443`

Comment: This is what I got for the curl command:  *   Trying 151.101.0.223...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to pypi.org (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Users/lillymcleod/anaconda/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to pypi.org:443 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0

Comment: wait, is it pointing to localhost? 
> Connected to pypi.org (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
what does this output? `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: The first lines of my curl command are: 
`curl -v -sL https://pypi.org/simple/pip
*   Trying 151.101.192.223...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to pypi.org (151.101.192.223) port 443 (#0)`

Comment: ##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1          localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1                            localhost

Comment: Looks like this post is helpful here https://superuser.com/a/1053924 it looks like something is listening on localhost on port 443 and is forwarding everything to that. What does this output? `nc -v -w 2 pypi.org` My output is: 

Warning: Inverse name lookup failed for `151.101.128.223'
Warning: Inverse name lookup failed for `151.101.192.223'
Warning: Inverse name lookup failed for `151.101.0.223'
Warning: Inverse name lookup failed for `151.101.64.223'
Error: No ports specified for connection

Comment: This is what I get:                                                                                                          
nc -v -w 2 pypi.org 443
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
 outif lo0
 src 127.0.0.1 port 58935
 dst 127.0.0.1 port 1110
 rank info not available
 TCP aux info available

Connection to pypi.org port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!

Comment: Cool so according to that superuser post something is happening on port 1110 on that machine which is receiving all the of the requests for 443. Now run `nettop -nm tcp` and look for what process is running on port `1110` and then kill that process or stop it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I killed the processes and I was able to download aws cli.

Comment: sw8 no problem dawg

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct so it shows up for other people having similar issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case was that there was another program running locally which was receiving all requests on port `443`. The cURL request failed with the error:

`Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to pypi.org:443` but that was because it was connecting using `127.0.0.1`.

```
 Trying 151.101.0.223... * TCP_NODELAY set * Connected to pypi.org (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0) * ALPN, offering http/1.1 * Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH * successfully set certificate verify locations: * CAfile: /Users/lillymcleod/anaconda/ssl/cacert.pem CApath: none * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22): * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1): * Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to pypi.org:443 * Curl_http_done: called premature == 0 * Closing connection 0
```

This post https://superuser.com/questions/1045431/curl-connecting-to-localhost-127-0-0-1-instead-of-destination-ip was helpful in determining which program was running using the following commands:

```
# Finds the ports receiving requests 
nc -v -w 2 YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE YOUR_PORT_HERE
```

```
# Find the applications running on the ports
nettop -nm tcp
```

Once the application was killed the pip install command worked as expected again.